# paypal in android webview and firefox

Tags: android, firefox, post, paypal, webview

I have a business account in paypal and I am utilizing it for an item selling website. When the user purchases the item from the website, the payment process takes place. While the process is happening, the process sequence sends the following data to paypal,

“

```
<INPUT type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">

<INPUT type="hidden" value="payment@example.com" name="business">

<INPUT type="hidden" value="Bag" name="item_name">

<INPUT type="hidden" name="custom" value="55">               

<INPUT type="hidden" value="http://mywebsite.com/test.php" name="return">

<INPUT type="hidden" value="1" name="no_note">

<INPUT type="hidden" value="USD" name="currency_code">

<INPUT type="hidden" value="http://mywebsite.com/test.php">

<INPUT type="hidden" value="http://mywebsite.com/test.php" name="cancel_return">

<INPUT type="hidden" value="102" name="amount">

<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Thangaraj">

<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="345 Lark Ave">

<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Lavis Nagar">

<input type="hidden" name="city" value="San Jose">

<input type="hidden" name="state" value="CA">

<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="95121">

<input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">

<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="123">

<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="123">

<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="1238">

<input type="hidden" name="email" value="jdoe@zyzzyu.com">
```

“.

The payment process is getting completed successfully. The Post payment process works well on all browsers except MOZILA FIREFOX and android browsers and web view.

When redirecting back to merchant site, the following alert is given in firefox along with `continue` and `cancel` options

“

```
Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.



Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?
```

”.

When the process is at paypal site when I click continue the process gets completed successfully, whereas when I click the continue after the auto redirecting to the merchant site the page gets blank due to empty POST data from paypal.

In Android based browsers and webview the alert message is not shown as firefox has shown, but the redirecting to merchant site returns blank page , as POST is empty.

Please help me to resolve this problem as soon as possible because the site is in live.Thank you for considering this post